# How to make jointjs paper responsive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jointjs

I just discover javascript library JointJs and I implemented a graph with paper and rects.

But I can't make it responsive when I reduce the browser size my graph doesn't display correctly.

How can I make my paper responsive with jointjs ?

Answer (score 7):

You can initially set the paper to be the same dimensions as it's containing element, but that's only calculated initially when the paper is created. If you want to paper to change size as you resize your browser, you'll need to react to resize events.

Firstly, you'll need to set overflow to hidden on your container, otherwise its dimensions will stretch to fit its child, and it won't shrink if you shrink the browser.

```
#modelCanvas {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You'll have to make sure your `#modelCanvas`element will stretch to fill available space by some method, either setting `height: 100%` (in situations where that will work) or using flexbox or absolute positioning.

Secondly, you'll need a resize event handler

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var canvas = $('#modelCanvas');
    paper.setDimensions(canvas.width(), canvas.height());
});
```

Comment: With this solution sometimes the cells get lost when the window is resized to smaller. Is there a way to setdimensions for the cell element too during window resize

Comment: You can do anything in the resize event handler. You could call `paper.scale()` (and possibly also `paper.setOrigin()`) to change the view to include all the details you had before, but you'll need to figure out what arguments to pass to those.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs on setDimensions (http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.2/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.setDimensions), you can set `width: '100%', height: '100%'` and then control the responsive display with your css.

Then, something like:

```
$(window).on('resize', joint.util.debounce(function() {
    paper.scaleContentToFit({ padding: 10 });
}));
```

and/or also set a `min-width/min-height` in px to the paper in css and add an `overflow: auto` to the parent.

Comment: I do not see that anywhere in the linked documentation, and it doesn't work, at least for me

Comment: Worked for me. It's in the documentation, at least in the new version: https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.3/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.setDimensions

Answer (score 4):

I Recommend using a responsive layout css such as bootstrap I personally recommend pure css (http://purecss.io) and the rest is easy once you set a base layout for the html page which contains the JointJS paper.

For example let's suppose you made the html base and you created specifically a div container called "modelCanvas" this div was made with a responsive css (For this example I used pure CSS).

> `<div id="modelCanvas" style="height:100%;width:100%; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;background-image:url(../res/tiny_grid.png);background-repeat:repeat;">`

Now into the JS part of your web site you, we'll initialize required JointJS paper and graph init

```
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
 el: $('#modelCanvas'),
 gridSize: 10,
 height: $('#modelCanvas').height(),
 width: $('#modelCanvas').width(),
 gridSize: 1,
 model: graph,
});
```

Now the JointJS paper is responsive 
Best, 
AG

Comment: `$('#modelCanvas').width()` equals to 0 in my case. For it helps somebody.

Comment: Not the best answer as this isn't truly responsive (ie this wouldn't help turning a phablet from landscape to portrait) as changing of media break point afte the initial load won't update the paper.

SpoonMeiser's answer bellow is better as it includes the javascript support so that it is truly responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the size of the `div` containing your paper:

```
document.getElementById("your-paper-container").setAttribute("style", "height: " + window.innerHeight + "px; overflow: scroll;");
```

You could change the code `window.innterHeight` to a variable if you have some additional elements within your page:

```
headers = 210;
height = window.innerHeight - headers;
document.getElementById("paper-container").setAttribute("style", "height: " + height + "px; overflow: scroll;");
```